# How to return a new table after modifying the columns, instead of changing the original table?

Tags: alter-table, dolphindb, tablecolumn, edit-in-place

How to return a new table without changing the original one when I use `tmpTB.replaceColumn!(args)?` Is there a parameter like `inplace=False` in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

In DolphinDB, all the functions with "!" will change the original object. The only function to replace columns is the `replaceColumn!` function. You can assign the original table to a new table variable before modifying it. Or you can use the `copy` function as follows:

```
tmpTB.copy().replaceColumn!(args)
```